# C - drawing in a bitmap

Tags: c, bitmap, projectile

I have to calculate the flight path of a projectile and draw the result in a bitmap file. So far I'm pretty clueless how to do that.

Would it be a good idea to safe the values of the flight path in a struct and transfer it to the bitmap file? 
Do you have any other suggestions how it could be done in a better way?

Comment: Can you use a drawing library? see [cairo](http://cairographics.org/). You can draw your path in a device independent way, and then write the image buffer to many file formats.

Comment: Unfortunately only C standard libraries are allowed to use.

Comment: The quick approach would be to fix the size of your output bitmap and set all the pixels to "off".  Then loop through each pixel and say, "if this pixel lies on my curve, set it 'on'".  You'll need to map curve coordinates to pixel indexes.  If you are making a .bmp bitmap, the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) page will show you the format.  You should read about [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) for help with [rasterization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation).

Comment: @indiv: No need for such heavy artillery here like a Bresham line. For the basics using the X axis for distance, Y for height, and plotting a single pixel every column is easy, and sufficient. If going for aesthetic, a contiguous line may be achieved from this by simply outputting a pixel column from the previous value to the current.

Comment: Thank you so far, but may I ask you to explain the linedrawing in a little more detailed way? Can't quite understand the idea yet.

Comment: You may want to have X for distance, Y for altitude. For the simpler approach, for every X, you just plot a pixel at the respective Y. If the angle of shooting the projectile is <=45 degrees, (assuming 1:1 scale), this gives a fine result. Otherwise, to get a contiguous line, you may want to plot columns, starting from the Y at the X-1 position, to the Y at X. (For example, say, at X=10 you have Y=23, then at X=11, you have Y=25. At X=11, you draw a column from Y=23 to Y=25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to produce an image file without much hassle with only standard C library tools is most likely writing a **bmp** file. For start, check the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) on this file format, it gives a quite complete description of it.

If you don't want to go too deep in that, save for example a 640x480 or so empty 24 bit ("truecolor") `.bmp` image, and rip out it's header for your use. Depending on the program you use to save your image, you might end up with varying header size, however since the data is not compressed, it is fairly easy isolate the header. For a 640x480 image the data will be exactly 921600 bytes long, anything preceding it is the header.

From here the colors are (usually) in RGB order, bottom to top row, left to right. Experimenting a little should give you the proper results.

If you only have the standard C libraries to work with, it is unlikely there is anything much simpler to implement. Of course this case you will have to write a pixel matrix (so no much assistance for solving the actual problem you want to image), but that's true for any image format (maybe except if you rather aim for creating an [**SVG** for a twist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), it is neither too hard, just XML).

Comment: BMP files are 100 times more complicated than something like XPM, which I would recommend, unless you're stuck with using Windows.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: The irony is I wrote this post on a Linux box, no windows here as far as the eye can see (Well, living in a cellar has it's problems, this is one of them). Yes, XPM is simple if your program is on the "receiver" end of the image data. If you need to produce it, outputting binary may be easier (of course unless you go in actually understanding the BMP header). The poster might also have to produce the program to someone who only has Windows (smells school assignment).

Comment: Unfortunately we have to use the BPM file. Thanks for your explanation guys! I guess we will try it with a struct mentioned in the actual question above. But if we have all those points set - any ideas how to connect them properly?